# Bounty Points Refund

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I have offered bounty of +50  on [My question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460910/net-frameworks-initialization-error). The bounty period is overed but bounty points not refunded any reason?

Comment: @Arjan, I want to know the reason about not to refunded eventhough bounty period is expired

Comment: Hmmm, when bernd_k read that page, he did find the answer...

Comment: the fact that bounties are not refundable is mentioned in many places during the bounty process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.